# how to improve accuracy of edge detector algorithm?

Tags: graphics, opencv

I want to use Canny edge or Sobel edge algorithm in opencv to detect my image's edge.

It works well when I take the object(paper) with dark background.
But the quality is low when the background color is similar to the object's.

Only the edge brodered on the shadow is clear. If the shadow is not so clear, the quality is not good enough.

So is there any good ways to improve it ?

Comment: In computer science, performance usually means processing speed. If you refer to processing quality, not speed, please rephrase your question, so it will be easier understood. The usula words for this are  "improve quality", buty you should make clear what exactly you want to improve

Comment: thanks your tip @vasile. :) My eng is not very well

Comment: It would help if you provided some sample images.

Comment: Try looking [here](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut5.html) particularly at the histogram equalization.  If your image has low contrast that should help quite a bit.  If you already have high contrast I don't know any way to help.

Answer (score 0):

Remember an edge means a boundary which represents the change in the distribution of the colour or texture..So if u keep an object in  a similar color background then how can a edge detector finds strong edges...

Anyway the problem has a solution too,

If the Background and object colors are different then for better edge detection you can use [Frei-Chen edge detector](http://rastergrid.com/blog/2011/01/frei-chen-edge-detector/)

If your background and object are a bit similar in RGB space then try to convert it into HSV or Ycbcr space and apply edge detection or segmentation techniques...

Hope it is uesful...